# input into vector without pre_defined length...?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose, i want to add all the elements in the vector and want to print the result out. the number of elements that i want to enter is not fixed.
let the input be:
 
3
5 2 8 5
34 64 23 10 8 12 5 4
 
95 22 1 3 531 5 13 1  3 1 

Her the 1st line is the test case // ie. 3 
and the other 3 lines are the user input

Comment: What do you mean? `std::vector` usually doesn't have a predefined length (though it can have one). Post your code please. The usual way is to take the input and `push_back()` those values to the `std::vector`.

Comment: What kind of error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Show what you have tried and how it fails. If you have no idea where to start, you probably need a good book to learn some basics. Have a look at different kind of loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reserve some space for your vector, you can take a look at [std::vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) function.

You can create a 2D vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size;    
    cin >> size;
    vector<vector<int> > vec;
    vec.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        vector<int> input;
        int number;
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        while (ss >> number) input.push_back(number);
        vec.push_back(input);
    }

    for (auto i: vec)
        for (auto j: i)
            cout << j << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you've made a typo with `vec.resize(size);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string line;
int n;
vector<int> v;

getline(cin, line);
istringstream stream(line);
while (stream >> n )
    v.push_back(n);

for(auto i=v.begin();i!=v.end();i++){
    cout << *i << " ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how it works and why it's a good solution to the problem?